# Laravel + Next.js SSR

Tags: laravel, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a project developed with Laravel + Next.js in SSR, I'm trying to access the url through an external link, but it doesn't get passed to next or it doesn't know what to do with it, as it always results in the project's home page.

```
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
  {
    "props": { "pageProps": {} },
    "page": "/{!! $request->path() !!}",
    "query": {{json_encode($request->query(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)}},
    "buildId": "FUO8j4aqy0TfB9QSYKYki",
    "nextExport": true,
    "autoExport": true,
    "isFallback": false,
    "scriptLoader": []
  }
```

I've tried to pass it this way and got no results.